Django devserver load once
I am trying to develop a django application it use paddelocr take sometime to initiate.
so when ever I am trying to change something and test it I have to wait 5 sec for the paddleocr to initiate again.
Is there a way to load the model only once when i start the dev server and not everytime I make some changes.
I have tried adding the model initalization in the setting.py assuming that it will only run only that didn't work.
I have also tried one of gpts suggestion of using thread but no luck so far

Welcome Irfan, please consider adding the relevant part of your code whenever you are posting such question.

You may want to use some kind of orchestration on your dev environment. Since the question is too broad, it may help to edit your question to add a minimal reproducible environment.

I may for example, suggest you use Celery to achieve this behavior, which will run another Python process (workers) that won't reload the code an will be independent of your Django server process. However, I can't tell you how to get this working without first taking a look at the revelant parts of your code (how are you running your Django server, minimal example of your settings.py, where/when/how are you loading your paddleocr model.

Django's dev server will reload everything on any code changes, so the answer may be as simple as disabling the reloading feature, but this comes with downsides like you lose reloading for everything else.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
